# Fix an element $h\in G$. Define $\varphi_h:G\to G$ by $\varphi_h(g)=hg$. Is that an isomorphism from $G$ to itself?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Fix an element $h$ $\in$ $G$. Define $\varphi_h:G\rightarrow G$ by $\varphi_h(g)=hg$

Is the following an isomorphism from $G$ to itself. How can I prove this?

Any hints or help would be great.

**Edit**: Using my knowledge of group homomorphisms, I have added an attempt at proving the question above.

For each $h \in G$ let $\varphi_h : G \rightarrow G$ be the morphism $\varphi_h(g) = \varphi_h(g) + \varphi_h(h) − \varphi_h(g + h)$

Then $\varphi_0(g) = \varphi(0) + \varphi(g) − \varphi(g + 0) = 0$ for all $g \in G$.

the image of $\varphi_h$ is a single point for all $h \in G$, and since $\varphi_h(0) = \varphi_h(0)+ \varphi_h(h)-\varphi_h(0+h) = 0$,
that point must be $0$.

It follows that $\varphi_h(g) = 0$ for all $g, h \in G$, therefore we always have
$\varphi_h(g) + \varphi_h(h) = \varphi_h(g + h)$ and $\varphi_h$ is a group isomomorphism.

This may be non-sensical for group isomorphisms. Apologies if so.

Comment: are you assuming $h$ is not the identity element?  Note that an isomorphism must map the identity element to the identity element

Comment: Yes, $h$ is not the identity element.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Usually one writes $R_h$ instead of $\varphi_h$, as $R$ stands for right translation. We have that $R_h$ is a bijection with inverse $R_{h^{-1}}$, but it is not a homomorphism. If you want a legit isomorphism, try the conjugation $C_h(g) = hgh^{-1}$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Isomorphisms send the identity element in the domain to that of the codomain. Indeed, $e=ee$, so for an isomorphism $\psi: G\to G$, we have

$$\begin{align}
e\psi(e)&=\psi(e)\\
&=\psi(ee)\\
&=\psi(e)\psi(e),
\end{align}$$

so cancel $\psi(e)$ on the right. Hence $e=\psi(e)$.

> But $\varphi_h(e)=he=h$ while $h\neq e$.